# Align text to the left of an image aligned to the middle

Tags: css, image, text, alignment

I am struggling with some things in CSS. As shown below, the image needs to be in center, and have
text left of it (close to the image, not with gap as shown in the fiddle). Please note that the image can change in width (it's a slider).

I have tried to just put a simple `margin: auto` into the image, and then a wrapper for the text (left side) with float right- so in my mind it should float to the image, but it does not (it creates a gap at the top) and float the text way to right (of course because there's a blank top space).

Is this possible in pure CSS?

What I tried to do is:

```
img{
    margin:auto;
    display:block;
}
.description{
    float:right;
}
```

[image: What I would like the result to look like]

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4su26Lbd/1)

Comment: First on my mind? Grid layout.

Comment: (OT) just out of curiosity, what is that right portion of space for?

Comment: It is used for wide images. So not wide images will off course leave some space :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of absolute positioning and table-cells will get the alignments you are looking for.

```css
.slider {
    width:1000px;
    height:500px;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.slider ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0;
}
.slider ul li {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}
.slider .slideContent {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.slider ul li .description {
    left: -200px; /*Subtract the width of the description*/
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
}
.slider ul li .pictureContainer {
    display: inline-block;
}
.slider ul li img {
    width: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}

/*Align contents to the middle*/
.slider ul li .slideMiddle {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 500px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="slideContent">
                    <div class="description">
                        <div class="slideMiddle">
                            <p>
                                Here should be some nice text near the image instead of left
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pictureContainer">
                        <div class="slideMiddle">
                            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SY9aY5S.jpg" />
                        </div>
                    </div>        
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- End slider -->
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4su26Lbd/8/

### Breakdown of why it works:

The first step is ensuring that the image is always centered.  To do this, I've created `<div class="slideContent">` that's set to **display: inline-block**.  This will do two things, it will cause the `.slideContent` div to become the width of the image, and it will be centered (because the `li` parent has `text-align: center;`.

```
.slider .slideContent {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```

Now to ensure that the description is always shown to the left of the image, we add `position: relative;` to `.slideContent`.

Then you set the `.description` to `width: 200px;`, and force it to the left using `position: absolute;` and then define `left: -200px;` to counter it's own width.

```
.slider ul li .description {
    left: -200px; /*Subtract the width of the description*/
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Finally, we want to vertically align the contents, so we create child divs with a class `.slideMiddle` and apply the following:

```
.slider ul li .slideMiddle {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 500px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The height definition matches the slider height, and the `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle` will cause the contents to be vertically aligned in the middle.

Comment: It is a very good example, but perhaps I did not explain it right :). In your case the image is not always centered. The image needs to be centered at all times. An then text align left to it.

Comment: I've updated the code to account for centering the image.  It required a bit more effort with absolute positionings.

Comment: I've also included a breakdown of why it works, hopefully to help you understand the principles.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your awesome answer: Axel. What I actually ended up doing with help of Alex answer was float the text to the left width a container (200px width), float the image to the left and then create an outer wrapper that has a width calculated from text container's width, plus image width and margin it auto :)